# Does ExternalInterface work on the file: protocol?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, file-uri

Can anyone confirm that ExternalInterface works on the `file:` protocol, or point to some docs that say that it will not?

Comment: Off-topic: I use XAMPP to debug flash "locally"

Comment: this isn't for testing, it's meant to be for code that will run on a cd

Comment: ok this is messed up, afaict the docs on [navigateToURL](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()) seem to suggest that I **should** use ExternalInterface for internal content WTF?

Comment: hmm they must mean we should use ExternalInterface for the local-trusted sandbox..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's starting to look like this will not work.. [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000350.html#wp123020) says:

> Scripting in either direction between
>   local HTML files and local SWF
>   files--for example, using the
>   ExternalInterface class--requires that
>   both the HTML file and SWF file
>   involved be in the local-trusted
>   sandbox. This is because the local
>   security models for browsers differ
>   from the Flash Player local security
>   model.

And this is what it says about the local-trusted sandbox:

> The local-trusted sandbox--Local SWF
>   files that are registered as trusted
>   (by users or by installer programs)
>   are placed in the local-trusted
>   sandbox. System administrators and
>   users also have the ability to
>   reassign (move) a local SWF file to or
>   from the local-trusted sandbox based
>   on security considerations (see
>   Administrative user controls and User
>   controls). SWF files that are assigned
>   to the local-trusted sandbox can
>   interact with any other SWF files and
>   can load data from anywhere (remote or
>   local).

So either a installer or user would have to put the swf in to a local-trusted-sandbox afaict..

Comment: note: ~hack mentioned [here](http://xs-sniper.com/blog/2011/01/04/bypassing-flash%E2%80%99s-local-with-filesystem-sandbox/)

Answer (score 3):

By default, ExternalInterface will throw Security Error #2060 if you try to use it from a file:// page. However, if you add the `<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>` option to your embed, it should be able to talk to JavaScript.

The [docs on ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) reference this, in the exception documentation for addCallback() and call().

**EDIT:** After discussing this further in the comments below, it appears that, although this works for me on Mac, it does not work on Windows. Erik's answer gives more details on why this is failing.

Comment: so using `<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>` prevents the Security Error?

Comment: Yep, it has in my experience. The docs reference this, as well as using `flash.system.Security.allowDomain(sourceDomain)` (updated my answer with a link, skip to the addCallback method).

Comment: so you used `flash.system.Security.allowDomain(sourceDomain)` within the actionscript in order to this to work on `file:`?

Comment: what did you use for `sourceDomain` when using the `file:` protocol btw?

Comment: It didn't require me to use allowDomain(). You can find my test code: http://pastie.org/1652310

Comment: so I did a `import flash.system.Security;` in the main class which is extending MovieClip, and then I did: `Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");` and `Security.allowDomain("*");` but this does not seem to be helping.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Here's a new example that includes that: http://pastie.org/1652499

Comment: It's odd that your example would work given what I read in the answer I posted, maybe it only applies to `addCallback` tho?

Comment: Ahh... I was testing on a Mac. I booted up the Windows VM, and I'm seeing what you're seeing: error #2060.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, have you considered using Air and taking advantage of the 'FileSystem'?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html