# flex ExternalInterface won't execute call() function

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

For some reason, the ExternalInterface.avaiable shows true, but it won't call alert(). Can anyone shed some light to this problem?

```
private function checkEI():void {
     eiStatus = ExternalInterface.available.toString();
     ExternalInterface.call("alert", "hi");
}
```

My config is here:

```
var params = {
    menu: "false",
    scale: "noScale",
    allowFullscreen: "true",
    allowScriptAccess: "always",
    bgcolor: "",
    wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
};
```

Looks like it has to do with not being in a webserver and the html file just being opened directly by the browser. Is there any way to get it to work without a webserver?

Comment: could you paste your `alert` function?

Comment: the alert function is the browser alert. everything works IF i'm running it from the web server instead of just opening the file. I'm sure it has something to do with a security policy or something.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify both `id` and `classid` in embed parameters. It helped me in all the browsers (especially IE).

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043663/1309352) my answer that I posted a while ago. Hope it helps.

**Extract:**

> I figured out that for some reason ExternalInterface.call doesn't work
> on a file:// and needs http(s)://
>
> So, anybody who is facing this problem, get your yourself a
> webserver(Apache) or a GAE for testing these kinds of things

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
ExternalInterface.call("javascript:alert", "hi");
```

On second thought,
Flash's security policy disallows the swf from calling a javascript in an html over the file protocol. You will get this error:
`#2060: Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller file: c:/test.swf cannot access file: c:\testhtml.htm`

I believe a similar question also exists at [Does ExternalInterface work on the file: protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241561/does-externalinterface-work-on-the-file-protocol)

Comment: `ExternalInterface.call("javascript:alert", "hi");` and
`ExternalInterface.call("alert", "hi");` 

What is the difference?

Comment: Well just a thought.

If I am calling a JavaScript function from html I usually use javascript:myFunction()

Comment: You can use. But your answer will not fit with the question.

Comment: well yeah, but in some browsers only `javascript:function()` works

Comment: Well I haven't done any javascript for a while now but I believe firefox 4 and less, and IE 7 used to do that

Comment: proof of what? I don't think any proof is required because these browsers are now almost extinct and it is pointless arguing about something that's not going to make a difference anyway.